# Access video from library ios

Tags: ios, video, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

How can I get all video files from camera roll library without using `UIImagePickerController`? Is there any chance?

Comment: Was a brilliant typo in the title ;)

Comment: Have a look at `ALAssetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:usingBlock:failureBlock:`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ALAssets to do that. [Look apple documentation.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAsset_Class/Reference/Reference.html)